# Apache POI Table of contents not updating

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, tableofcontents

I am using Apache POI XWPF components and java, to extract data from a .xml file into a word document. So far so good, but I am struggling to create a table of contents.

I have to create a table of contents at the start of the method and then I update it at the end to get all the new headers. Currently I use `doc.createTOC()`, where doc is a variable created from `XWPFDocument`, to create the table at the start and then I use `doc.enforceUpdateFields()` to update everything at the end of the document. But when I open the document after I ran the program, the table of contents is empty, but the navigation panel does include some of the headers I specified.

A comment recommended that I include some code. So i started off by create the document from a template:

```
XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("D://Template.docx"));
```

I then create a table of contents:

```
doc.createTOC();
```

Then throughout the method I add headers to the document:

```
XWPFParagraph documentControlHeading = doc.createParagraph();
documentControlHeading.setPageBreak(true);
documentControlHeading.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);
documentControlHeading.setStyle("Tier1Header");
```

After all the headers are added, I want to update the document so that all the new headers will appear in the table of contents. I do this buy using the following command:

```
doc.enforceUpdateFields();
```

Comment: Give us a stripped down version of your code that exhibits the problem, then maybe someone can help.

Comment: Hi. I added some code to the initial question, hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

//Your docx template should contain the following or something similar text //which will be searched for and replaced with a WORD TOC.

//${TOC}

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, OpenXML4JException {
        XWPFDocument docTemplate = null;
        try {
            File file = new File(PATH_TO_FILE); //"C:\\Reports\\Template.docx";
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            docTemplate = new XWPFDocument(fis);
             generateTOC(docTemplate);
            saveDocument(docTemplate);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (docTemplate != null) {
                docTemplate.close();
            }
        }
    }   

private static void saveDocument(XWPFDocument docTemplate) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    FileOutputStream outputFile = null;
    try {
        outputFile = new FileOutputStream(OUTFILENAME);
        docTemplate.write(outputFile);
    } finally {
        if (outputFile != null) {
            outputFile.close();
        }
    }
}


public static void generateTOC(XWPFDocument document) throws InvalidFormatException, FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        String findText = "${TOC}";
        String replaceText = "";
        for (XWPFParagraph p : document.getParagraphs()) {
            for (XWPFRun r : p.getRuns()) {
                int pos = r.getTextPosition();
                String text = r.getText(pos);
                if (text != null && text.contains(findText)) {
                    text = text.replace(findText, replaceText);
                    r.setText(text, 0);
                    addField(p, "TOC \\o \"1-3\" \\h \\z \\u");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

private static void addField(XWPFParagraph paragraph, String fieldName) {
    CTSimpleField ctSimpleField = paragraph.getCTP().addNewFldSimple();
    // ctSimpleField.setInstr(fieldName + " \\* MERGEFORMAT ");
    ctSimpleField.setInstr(fieldName);
    ctSimpleField.addNewR().addNewT().setStringValue("<<fieldName>>");
}
```

Comment: Update: add the following line just before the save method:
docTemplate.enforceUpdateFields();

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... I am looking at the `createTOC()` method code, and it appears that it looks for styles that look like `Heading #`. So `Tier1Header` would not be found. Try creating your text first, and use styles like `Heading 1` for your headings. Then add the TOC using `createTOC()`. It should find all the headings when the TOC is created. I do not know if `enforceUpdateFields()` affects the TOC.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your comment. It works but the TOC is now at the end of the document. Is there any way I can specify where the TOC should be generated? The enforceUpdateFields() did work for the TOC, but it only updated it in the navigation panel, and not in the word document itself.

Comment: Sorry, don't know the answer here, it is down in the weeds, and I don't have time to dig through the source and find it. Word documents are kind of an extra in POI. And I don't know if there are even any committers working on it right now. HWPF doesn't even have a way to do a TOC. It would be easier if the `createToc()` method would return the TOC so you could add lines yourself if necessary. It is not automatic though.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code of `createTOC()`, obtained by inspecting `XWPFDocument.class`:

```
public void createTOC() {
    CTSdtBlock block = getDocument().getBody().addNewSdt();
    TOC toc = new TOC(block);
    for (XWPFParagraph par : this.paragraphs) {
        String parStyle = par.getStyle();
        if ((parStyle != null) && (parStyle.startsWith("Heading"))) try {
            int level = Integer.valueOf(parStyle.substring("Heading".length())).intValue();
            toc.addRow(level, par.getText(), 1, "112723803");
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, it adds to the TOC all paragraphs having styles named "`HeadingX`", with X being a number. But, unfortunately, that's not sufficent. The method, in fact, is bugged/uncomplete in its implementation.

The page number passed to `addRow()` is always `1`, it's not even calculated.
So, at the end, you will have a TOC with all your paragraphs and the trailing dots giving the proper indentation, but the pages will be always equal to "1".

---

**EDIT**
...but, there's a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40235909/creating-a-table-of-contents-for-a-xwpfdocument-with-page-numbers-indication/40264237#40264237).