# Creating a Table of Contents for a XWPFDocument with page numbers' indication

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am actually generating a Word Document with Apache POI, and I need to automatically create a Table of Contents (TOC) that references the paragraphs, with their page's indication.

This is the code I am using (I omit preconditions and internal methods' body):

```
XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.openOrCreate(new File(document)));

String strStyleId = "Index Style";
addCustomHeadingStyle(doc, strStyleId, 1);

XWPFParagraph documentControlHeading = doc.createParagraph();
changeText(documentControlHeading, "First try");
documentControlHeading.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);
documentControlHeading.setPageBreak(true);
documentControlHeading.setStyle(strStyleId);

XWPFParagraph documentControlHeading1 = doc.createParagraph();
changeText(documentControlHeading1, "Second try");
documentControlHeading1.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);
documentControlHeading1.setPageBreak(true);
documentControlHeading1.setStyle(strStyleId);

doc.createTOC();
```

When I open the resulting document, I am getting this result (see blue squares):

[image]

In the left part, I can see the generated TOC. So far, so good.
In the document's body, however, I can just see a static text "Table of Contents", with no indications at all (neither paragraphs nor pages). I cannot even interact with it.

If I'd click on the menu entry "Table of Contents" (red square on the upper-left corner), the "real" Table of Content that I want is being generated (follow the arrow, of course...).

**My question is:** *how can I achieve the second result (red TOC) from code?*

Thank you so much.

*Side note:* I even tried putting `doc.enforceUpdateFields();` after `doc.createTOC();`, but every reference of the TOC disappears, this way.

@Sucy, I add the methods that you requested. Don't know if you can find them useful, though:

```
/*
 * Adds a custom style with the given indentation level at the given document.
 */
private static void addCustomHeadingStyle(XWPFDocument docxDocument, String strStyleId, int headingLevel) {

    CTStyle ctStyle = CTStyle.Factory.newInstance();
    ctStyle.setStyleId(strStyleId);

    CTString styleName = CTString.Factory.newInstance();
    styleName.setVal(strStyleId);
    ctStyle.setName(styleName);

    CTDecimalNumber indentNumber = CTDecimalNumber.Factory.newInstance();
    indentNumber.setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(headingLevel));

    // lower number > style is more prominent in the formats bar
    ctStyle.setUiPriority(indentNumber);

    CTOnOff onoffnull = CTOnOff.Factory.newInstance();
    ctStyle.setUnhideWhenUsed(onoffnull);

    // style shows up in the formats bar
    ctStyle.setQFormat(onoffnull);

    // style defines a heading of the given level
    CTPPr ppr = CTPPr.Factory.newInstance();
    ppr.setOutlineLvl(indentNumber);
    ctStyle.setPPr(ppr);

    XWPFStyle style = new XWPFStyle(ctStyle);

    // is a null op if already defined
    XWPFStyles styles = docxDocument.createStyles();

    style.setType(STStyleType.PARAGRAPH);
    styles.addStyle(style);

}

/*
 * Changes the text of a given paragraph.
 */
public static void changeText(XWPFParagraph p, String newText) {
    if (p != null) {
        List<XWPFRun> runs = p.getRuns();
        for (int i = runs.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            p.removeRun(i);
        }

        if (runs.size() == 0) {
            p.createRun();
        }

        XWPFRun run = runs.get(0);
        run.setText(newText, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give me show your changeText() and addCustomHeadingStyle() method, thanks!

Comment: @Sucy. I have added them. Hope that you can find them useful.

Comment: Do you have any ideas about  [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43335464/how-to-set-table-of-contents-font-style-including-font-color-font-size-and-bol) thanks!

Comment: Maybe I should reproduce style.xml, but I don't know the relationship  connects document.xml and styles.xml, and how to set styles ids inside document.xml to connect concrete text part with concrete style. I should expend huge effort to do this. Do your have any ideas?

Comment: @Sucy No, I am sorry. I imported the addCustomHeadingStyle() method as is from an online discussion in order to achieve a style, but I have never explored styles in a deeper way. Plus, I don't use xml files as you say...sorry but I can't be of further help.

Comment: It is really a tricky problem for changing TOC's style.Thank you all the same!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The XWPF classes as you have seen are a work in progress, with no real overarching architecture. That will change over time as we work on it, but in the mean time you can try to add a simple TOC field to a paragraph in this way.

```
XWPFParagraph p;
...
// get or create your paragraph
....
CTP ctP = p.getCTP();
CTSimpleField toc = ctP.addNewFldSimple();
toc.setInstr("TOC \\h");
toc.setDirty(STOnOff.TRUE);
```

This will create a Table of contents with hyperlinks to the pages, it should be recalculated when Word opens it, and the table of contents will be based on predefined HeaderX styles.

Comment: Thank you so much! This really is a valuable answer, I've seen many posts with similar doubts that still unsolved. I just had to do `toc.setDirty(STOnOff.TRUE);`, instead than `toc.setDirty(STOnOff.Enum.TRUE);`.

Comment: Thanks, I adjusted my answer based on your comment.

Comment: Hey, when I try this I have 2 problems:
* The field is not included into the document if I do not set a default text (`toc.addNewR().addNewT().setStringValue("x");`)
* Neither `toc.setDirty(STOnOff.TRUE);` nor `document.enforceUpdateFields();` seem to force any word processing program to update the fields, do you know why?

Answer (score 4):

I've solved the mystery and, unfortunately (for people having the same problem), there's no good news. <strike>Apache POI's `createTOC()` is bugged (to be honest, it seems a method whose implementation has been started but never completed in a proper way)</strike> (please, consider jmarkmurphy's accepted answer).

The [Documentation](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument.html) doesn't explain anything about the method itself (it just reports the signature, and nothing more), and that's suspect.

Watching at the `XWPFDocument`'s class code:

```
public void createTOC() {
    CTSdtBlock block = getDocument().getBody().addNewSdt();
    TOC toc = new TOC(block);
    for (XWPFParagraph par : this.paragraphs) {
        String parStyle = par.getStyle();
        if ((parStyle != null) && (parStyle.startsWith("Heading"))) try {
            int level = Integer.valueOf(parStyle.substring("Heading".length())).intValue();
            toc.addRow(level, par.getText(), 1, "112723803");
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Apache POI searches for paragraphs having style named "HeadingX", with X being a number. So, my variable `strStyleId` should have been valorized as `Heading1`, as an example. But this doesn't solved the problem. In fact, `createTOC()` always passes `1` as the page number to the `addRow()` method, that always sets the page as 1, this way. It does absolutely nothing in order to get that dinamically.

That's the final, unuseful result (as you can see, it's also a "fake" TOC, and not the one that you can create via Microsoft Word using the red-squared button in the question):

[image]

So, page numbers for a Word document cannot be retrieved dinamically (as I read in other posts), and even Apache POI seems unable to do that, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

```
toc.setInstr("TOC \\h");
```

h switch has to be used with '\', not '/', because it works correctly only with '\'. More details about using TOC switches: [Use Word's TOC field to fine-tune your table of contents](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/use-words-toc-field-to-fine-tune-your-table-of-contents/)

Comment: Instead of posting links as answer add some text to explanation how this answer help to OP in fixing current issue.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had had the same problem, but I wanted to add a ToC with depth=2 (exclude heading 3). I've created a copy and added the ToC manually in the Word document and rename both from .docx to .zip.

Inside each zip document, there's an XML file located in document.zip/word/document.xml. This document is the document content.

I've compared both XML files and found that Word added the following value when you add a ToC:

```
<w:fldSimple w:instr="TOC \o "1-2" \h \z \u"/>
```

I've updated my code using this:

```
CTP ctP = paragraph.getCTP();
CTSimpleField toc = ctP.addNewFldSimple();
toc.setInstr("TOC \\o \"1-2\" \\h \\z \\u");
toc.setDirty(STOnOff.ON);
```

When you open the document, Word will ask you to update the references and the ToC becomes perfect. Since I want the generation process fully automated I'm still working on that part.

Answer (score 0):

If someone still looking for the answer, i followed the suggestion provided by @jmarkmurphy.

Below is the working code

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.math.BigInteger;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.BreakType;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFStyle;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFStyles;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTDecimalNumber;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTOnOff;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTP;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTPPr;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTSettings;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTSimpleField;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTString;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTStyle;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STOnOff;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STStyleType;

public class ApachePOIWordTOCDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();

    doc.createTOC();
    addCustomHeadingStyle(doc, "heading 1", 1);
    addCustomHeadingStyle(doc, "heading 2", 2);
    addCustomHeadingStyle(doc, "heading 3", 3);

    // the body content
    XWPFParagraph paragraph = doc.createParagraph();

    CTP ctP = paragraph.getCTP();
    CTSimpleField toc = ctP.addNewFldSimple();
    toc.setInstr("TOC \\h");
    toc.setDirty(STOnOff.TRUE);
    

    XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();

    paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
    run = paragraph.createRun();
    run.setText("Heading 1");
    paragraph.setStyle("heading 1");

    paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
    run = paragraph.createRun();
    run.addBreak(BreakType.PAGE);
    run.setText("Heading 2");
    paragraph.setStyle("heading 2");
    
    paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
    run = paragraph.createRun();
    run.addBreak(BreakType.PAGE);
    run.setText("Heading 3");
    paragraph.setStyle("heading 3");
    
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("createTOC.docx");
    doc.write(fos);
    }

    private static void addCustomHeadingStyle(XWPFDocument docxDocument, String strStyleId, int headingLevel) {

    CTStyle ctStyle = CTStyle.Factory.newInstance();
    ctStyle.setStyleId(strStyleId);

    CTString styleName = CTString.Factory.newInstance();
    styleName.setVal(strStyleId);
    ctStyle.setName(styleName);

    CTDecimalNumber indentNumber = CTDecimalNumber.Factory.newInstance();
    indentNumber.setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(headingLevel));

    // lower number > style is more prominent in the formats bar
    ctStyle.setUiPriority(indentNumber);

    CTOnOff onoffnull = CTOnOff.Factory.newInstance();
    ctStyle.setUnhideWhenUsed(onoffnull);

    // style shows up in the formats bar
    ctStyle.setQFormat(onoffnull);

    // style defines a heading of the given level
    CTPPr ppr = CTPPr.Factory.newInstance();
    ppr.setOutlineLvl(indentNumber);
    ctStyle.setPPr(ppr);

    XWPFStyle style = new XWPFStyle(ctStyle);

    // is a null op if already defined
    XWPFStyles styles = docxDocument.createStyles();

    style.setType(STStyleType.PARAGRAPH);
    styles.addStyle(style);

    }
}
```