# How to generate directory(bookmark) in poi word(XWPF)?

Tags: apache-poi

everyone, I want to generate a word with POI (XWPF), and I want to generate directory in my .docx File. When I click this directory I can jump to corresponding chapter. I am a new bird in POI word, so I cannot find some method for solving my problems. Can anyone give me some advice? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are looking for Table of Contents. There is an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40264237/2296441

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a Table of Contents for a XWPFDocument with page numbers' indication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40235909/creating-a-table-of-contents-for-a-xwpfdocument-with-page-numbers-indication)

Comment: Thank you so much, your advice is very helpful for me.

Comment: If it helps you, please up vote